# Creating Emulators for the current Android phones

Tags: android, emulation

As I do not have the money to buy all the Android phones, is there a resource somewhere or can somebody suggest the settings that would best emulate the Nexus, Motrola Droid and HTC Magic etc.  Some users are reporting problems with my app and I am thinking it may be due to the screen sizes.

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are the settings I use:

- [**Nexus One**](http://www.google.com/phone/static/en_US-nexusone_tech_specs.html) - **Target:** Android 2.1 - **Skin:** WVGA800
- [**Droid**](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/Mobile-Phones/ci.Motorola-DROID-US-EN.alt) - **Target:** Android 2.0 - **Skin:** WVGA854
- [**Hero**](http://www.htc.com/www/product/hero/specification.html) - **Target:** Android 1.6 - **Skin:** HVGA

You're not going to get an exact match for the physical devices in the Emulator, but the screen sizes are correct.

Also, due to firmware updates some of these phones can have different firmware levels on.  For example, a Droid could be on 2.0 or 2.0.1.  The levels above are based on the lowest level each phone could be running.

Comment: Ive noticed skins available for some of these devices - anyone managed to use them in their emulator configs?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058450/why-not-standard-android-emulators) earlier question is relevant, but does not directly list configurations you can use.