# Testing an application for Android

Tags: android

I was wondering if any one had compiled a list of the most commonly used Android devices so I can get an idea of what I should test for. Even better would be suggested configurations for emulating each device.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Google publishes any stats on particular devices, they just have this data on [platform versions](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) and [screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html).  However, that could get you started.

Based on that data, I'd test at least one configuration with API versions 1.5, 1.6 and 2.1, and versions with medium and high density resolutions.

If you wanted to test physical devices, I would guess that the G1 and the Droid would be the top two... G1 would give you the lower API versions, and Droid would give you the 2.1.

Depending on your application that may be sufficient.  Applications that make heavy use of OpenGL extensions might need to test further, since that is the area where there is the most difference from device to device. I don't think that the emulator is sufficient for that.  See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093594/opengl-extensions-available-on-different-android-devices) on the differences.

Comment: That is exactly what I was getting at. I could find a ton of potential devices that I could test for, I was just wondering what everyone else was testing.

Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have Google Search as well, but here's what I can find:

- There's a [long list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Android_devices) of Android devices on Wikipedia. On many of the phones it lists screen resolution and OS version.
- A question about "Current" phones from a few months ago:
  [Creating Emulators for the current Android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086269/creating-emulators-for-the-current-android-phones)
- OS version usage: 
  http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html
- A phone usage poll (only 149 votes, but still suggestive):
   http://www.phonesreview.co.uk/2010/05/11/what-is-the-most-popular-google-android-phone-readers-choice/